# signalr The connection id is in the incorrect format

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I have a project build from mvc4 c# razor engine.
I added latest signalr nuget package 1.0.1
My project uses form authentication. 
each time the client goes from login to logout and vise versa I get an error on the client :

```
> "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error -
> http://myhost:51090/signalr/abort?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=uIJvYLP3T0GdHaowIlS4uPDA19ukUy7TaW8dcXoPfma4Mr52uoe7PLK9Hh3ip17X_3RbFXx92yEa7nxYVHaCiRAWVE5e05vvpLD0_blb94eUwdkXbmhkRPM2_Z590A64VBF2-eLB_8wCWq-dmkkkbe6EqP6c9YXN3WRF5IyNYkB6Wkom7O1ZoDavQQ0UWvok0"
```

and in the server side :

```
 The connection id is in the incorrect format.
```

do I need to consider working  with signalr in different way (from https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Hubs) then with authentication ?

Comment: Have you solved your problem and if yes - how? :)

Comment: Yes, Client should be disconnected before doing FormAuthentication.SignOut need to call from client side to hub.stop()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are logging out (modifying your user) while you have an active SignalR connection.

The reason why this is happening is because on the abort request on the server we check to see if the connectionId is associated with the correct user.  Therefore logging out while the connection is still active results in you losing your user association and causing an error.

To fix this, stop the SignalR connection before logging out.

Comment: Can you share a code sample that shows how we can stop all signalr connections for a given user?

Comment: That'd be a pretty complex code snippet.  Essentially you need to track all the ConnectionId's associated with a user and then create a client side method that disconnects the client.  Once you have those two pieces, whenever you want to stop all the connections for a user you just invoke the client function to stop the connections for all the ConnectionId's associated with the user.

Comment: How can this be handled or tolerated when the client has no control over when it could be logged off? For example sso based token that got expired or was invalidate because the same credentials were used somewhere else? I am only talking about JS client. Eventually the client would be sent to sso because the token is not valid but even then I believe abort request is causing this exception. The HubPipelineModule.OnIncomingError is never called for this as far as I can tell.

Comment: in 0.2.0 the client will disconnect and therefore will have to be started fresh again.  This way you know when your credentials have been timed out or something else severely wrong happened with the SignalR connection, therefore you can tie into the disconnected event in and perform the logic that you'd like.