# SignalR - The connection id is in the incorrect format when using Windows and Anonymous authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, connection, signalr

I use SignalR 1.0.1 as a chat core for ASP.NET MVC3 application. Using IIS 7.5
There are two methods in MVC controller which provides access to chat views:
1. First method is public, allowing anonymous users to chat - no authorization.
2. Access to second method is restricted with `[Authorize]` attribute, for domain users - chat agents.
There is no explicitly specified authorization in the Hub.
For this scenario I involved both Windows and Anonymous authentication on IIS.
I also implemented custom Role Provider, which operates only in memory - not persisting anything to database.

What happens is that using '[Authorize]' attribute in controller method leads to responsing 500 from Hub, both when call is coming from authorized view, and the anonymous one:

Request (`send` is Hub method for sending messages):
`http://localhost:8101/signalr/send?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=VIXEZzWQSn5SNlA8RUy4iaOPDFdvuPBjMvFBiG2FLfvfxF347XHwtapsEV5ndU4OEI0Xb64W2ZRXTqwBiL2CXg2_JlTaTJ2RnVOj4bjvx6tQaYhAqTaXs9k2853GYqzd0`

Response:
`The connection id is in the incorrect format.`

```
Server stack trace:
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.GetConnectionId(HostContext context, String connectionToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequest(HostContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin.CallHandler.Invoke(IDictionary2 environment)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin.Handlers.HubDispatcherHandler.Invoke(IDictionary2 environment)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinCallContext.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object extraData)<br/><br/>
```

But notice, that connecting to Hub works fine, returns 200 OK:
`http://localhost:8101/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=dYOwFxa1mkgdpzw-jitRpWq9oxRlrTet8U_dAzWjFQEdGNJfVXeG7Op0NZZwvznxeNdJCuPT75CKzQqI9HRPThV3uEDt-Z2qtIl9E02gF481&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22chathub%22%7D%5D&tid=9`

I found little similiar thread here on stackoverflow:
[signalr The connection id is in the incorrect format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349043/signalr-the-connection-id-is-in-the-incorrect-format)

from which I understand, that when invoking my `Send` method, the Hub is processing request with `Identity` different than the one used to connect to Hub, OR Hub's `GetConnectionId` finds, that user is actually not authorized - but how it checks that assumption, when there is no authorization specified on the Hub itself?

Can someone put some light on this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SignalR signs both your connection id and your `Identity` together in order to create a new `connectionToken` every time you start a new connection. This `connectionToken` is then sent to the SignalR client as part of the `negotiate` response.

Every time you make a request to SignalR, whether it be a `connect`, `reconnect`, or `send` request, SignalR verifies that your `connectionToken` matches both your client's connection id AND `Identity`.

The `connectionToken` is essentially a CSRF token used in order to prevent attackers running third-party websites from surreptitiously making SignalR requests on behalf of shared clients. Obviously this doesn't help if you've enabled SignalR's cross-domain support, but the `connectionToken` still works the same in this case.

[Taylor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349043/signalr-the-connection-id-is-in-the-incorrect-format) was correct. You should `stop` and then `start` your SignalR connection when your client's `Identity` changes. This will force a new `negotiate` request which will give your client a new connection id with a new `connectionToken` signed with your client's updated `Identity`.

P.S. The server-sent events `connect` request isn't failing because it was established before your client's `Identity` was changed. The `connectionToken` is only checked at the request is received, but server-sent events keeps the response open indefinitely.

Comment: But the tricky part I found is that both `connect` and `send` are executed after authorization - user calls controller method decorated with `[Authorize]` what provides him a view where calling Hub takes place - so when calling `connect` from Javascript, the user is already authorized.  My understanding is that `Identity` is changed before any call to Hub - during MVC action execution.

Comment: Looking at your stack trace, it is pretty clear that your user's `Identity` has changed between the `negotiate` and the `send` request. This could have happened via an AJAX request or a session timeout.

Comment: I have the same scenario, can I make the caller disconnect from server side, inside my code to Login account controller method .if ValidateUser ok I want to disconnect the caller so he will have to connect again to the hub. how can I do it ?

Comment: I am facing the same issue calling a SignalR Hub via an iOS client. My flow is the following: 1. The user logs in calling a Login service that uses the WebSecurity.Login method 2. The Login service returns success. 3. A hub connection is openned to call a Test hub method (no connection is openned before login). 4. I get the above error. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

That's all true what you said and it actually takes place in my issue.
But I also found the the root cause:
One of main assumptions during design was to allow both anonymous users to use the chat without need to sign-in and the back-end users (agents) to sign-in to restricted area of chat using their Windows credentials.
So on the IIS manager I enabled both Anonymous authentication (allowing anonymous users to use the chat) and the Windows authentication (allowing agents to access using their Windows credentials).
MVC application is configured to use Windows authentication - the `[Authorize]` attribute mentioned in question, but only to restrict access for agent's view of chat.
What actually happens with above configuration is:
1. When client (agent) requests restricted View (let's say it's `/Chat/Agent`) the `[Authorize]` attribute initializes authentication (Windows)
2. Client-side Javascript requests `Negotiate`, what generates `connectionId` and binds it with client's  Windows `Identity`
3. Here is the tricky part: Because Hub not uses any authentication explicitly, calling `send` method does not result in any authentication request - IIS Anonymous authentication takes precedency before Windows authentication, and `send` request is sent with anonymous `Identity` - but in Hub actual `connectionId` is related to `Identity` passed in point 2.
This scenario leads to situation you described - `connect` is called with different `Identity` than `send` and Hub returns `The connection id is in the incorrect format.`