# SignalR - Reconnect event Response with 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: model-view-controller, signalr

i'm a bit new with signalr

i have developed a simple chat room (just connect to hub and begin chat) .. i tried it in my localhost and it was working perfectly without any interrupt ..that's good so far .

i uploaded then that site to online host .. i noticed that signalr connection ger failure after short time ..  i opened chrome console i found that he tried to reconnect again with the hub (despite it's never happend in my localhost to try to reconnect)
the request was as the Following

```
Request URL:http://x-strangers.com/signalr/reconnect?transport=serverSentEvents&messageId=d-7C5BF30A-B%2C0%7CC%2C4%7CD%2C1&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=2gLhobhAyeQi9GcNL%2FQTHDcBsz0Rgyc%2FUy4K%2FS5K6Kc0pQB%2FCsLATd2gYBZZ7dclT1EpGafRQkU7MC%2FHEUZTV7cldjc81%2BNYjmckQiS%2FbLcRZqU8GYYx6rPulazcdw89&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22strangershub%22%7D%5D&tid=4
Request Method:GET
Status Code:400 Bad Request
Remote Address:198.38.83.16:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Wed, 21 Jun 2017 20:47:11 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
Request Headers
view source
Accept:text/event-stream
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en;q=0.8,ar;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.4
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=zfgyzje0tvjfot4r1jpk2zg2
Host:x-strangers.com
Referer:http://x-strangers.com/Home/Strangers
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Query String Parameters
view source
view URL encoded
transport:serverSentEvents
messageId:d-7C5BF30A-B,0|C,4|D,1
clientProtocol:1.5
connectionToken:2gLhobhAyeQi9GcNL/QTHDcBsz0Rgyc/Uy4K/S5K6Kc0pQB/CsLATd2gYBZZ7dclT1EpGafRQkU7MC/HEUZTV7cldjc81+NYjmckQiS/bLcRZqU8GYYx6rPulazcdw89
connectionData:[{"name":"strangershub"}]
tid:4`
```

and the Response was Like the Following

```
The ConnectionId is in the incorrect format.
```

Eventually the Connection get Fail

Any Idea how to Fix This ??

Comment: read this answer here might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349043/signalr-the-connection-id-is-in-the-incorrect-format