# SignalR fails to reconnect with this error The ConnectionId is in the incorrect format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I made a simple chat application in ASP.NET MVC and SignalR using the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc).

Using fiddler, I see SignalR `connects` successfully, then sends a few requests for a few seconds to this path successfully:

> https://myaddress.com/signalr/poll?transport=longPolling&clientProtocol=1.5 //the rest

The last successful `post` takes a bit longer with this response:

> {"C":"d-223DA124-B,6|C,0|D,3|E,1","T":1,"M":[]}

Then after that SignalR sends repeated `reconnect` requests to this address which fail:

> https://myaddress.com/signalr/reconnect?transport=longPolling&clientProtocol=1.5& // the rest

with this response:

> The ConnectionId is in the incorrect format.

What possibly is wrong and how to fix it? is it something wrong on my server which probably blocks these requests? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"T": 1` in the response means that the server told the client to try to reconnect. The server sends `"T": 1` if the server is shutting down. I think that after the server is restarted it loses state and can no longer associate the connection Id with the user.

Comment: Thanks @Pawel. So why it happens on the server? I've no special code on the server, just override `OnConnected` `OnDisconnected` `OnReconnected` methods, and there save new users to an external storage. Can an `exception` in these methods cause the server to shut down?

Comment: Maybe it's because of the host that I've my MVC app on it?

Comment: You need to figure out if the server is shutting down. (T is set to 1 when [HostShutdownToken](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/1fba14fa3437e24c204dfaf8a18db3fce8acad3c/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Transports/LongPollingTransport.cs#L179) is cancelled - so it seems the server is shutting down). Then you need to figure out why.

Comment: Sorry by the server you mean my whole ASP.NET MVC website, or just SignalR Hub?

Comment: Entire website - probably including appdomain recycles (or the entire server - i.e. you stop IIS)

Answer (score 0):

If you're signing in the users for chatting, they might be getting logged out somewhere during the last post and you might be getting this error. Check [signalr The connection id is in the incorrect format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349043/signalr-the-connection-id-is-in-the-incorrect-format).

Comment: No I've not implemented any authentication for SignalR